# Can Compatibility level be changed for a query in SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server-2019

In the past I have changed SQL Server compatibility level using an `Alter Database` statement. Is there a way to do it for an individual query rather than setting it for the complete database?

Comment: Compatibility is a database setting, not a connection setting. If you need to have an environment where things run under a certain compatibility mode, I suggest having a database created with that setting.

Comment: Thanks. Somehow I got the impression that starting with SQL Server 2019, it is possible

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you need a different compatibility level for objects rather than the database? If you elaborate, then there could be solutions to your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with later versions of SQL, (I believe SQL 2017 and afterward), you can add this as a query hint.

```
SELECT * FROM my_table QUERY_OPTIMIZER_COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL_100
```

for example, to run in 2008 mode. Or you could  change the 100 to 150 to run in 2019 compatibility mode or anywhere in-between.

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM FOO
OPTION(USE HINT('QUERY_OPTIMIZER_COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL_150'))
```

[QUERY_OPTIMIZER_COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL hint docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query?view=sql-server-ver15#use_hint)